# How do you install an extension from GitHub?

Tags: github

I'm contemplating to buy this extension from Firebear studio:

https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html

In order to move products from Magento 1.9.4 to Magento 2.

They have replied the following:

*In regard to Magento 1. You can use default magento export or in addition our free extension*

https://github.com/firebearstudio/iimagento1

*Note. This extension is no longer supported and we do not provide services to install and configure this extension.*

**Now, I've gone to that GitHub page, clicked EVERYWHERE and I can't find any installation instructions! How do I install this? Do I just upload the 2 files via FTP? How do I start the extension? Why does it not include any installation instructions while at the same time, the company who created it and points me to it, provides NO support?**

---

---

UPDATED on June 16th, 2023:

I've attempted to do what @Sohel Rana suggested = created the directories and uploaded the files as listed here:

https://github.com/firebearstudio/iimagento1/find/master

Then, I went into the Admin panel, done a reindex from the Admin panel and when I clicked to Clear Cache in the Admin panel, it (both front and back end) went into **Error 404.**

I then deleted the Cache and var folders, re-indexed and cleared Cache via SSH but Error 404 stayed on.

I even asked our hosting to Clear Cache and re-index - they have done that but the Error (404) remained.

I had to removed the folders and files I've put in and then the site (front and back end) came back.

**What have I done wrong and what do I need to do to make this work?**

Comment: This is M1 extension. Doesn't work with M2. Buy their paid M2 extension instead or convert above M1 extension to M2 extension.

Comment: @Sohel Rana - I'm sorry - I didn't explain it correctly. I will buy their M2 extension BUT I need to EXPORT orders from M1, then use their M2 extension to IMPORT it into M2. So I still need their Magento 1 extension as well!

Comment: Copy the app into your Magento 1 app directory. Clear the cache. That's it. Browse the M1 site, will install the M1 extension.

Comment: @Sohel Rana - Thank you for your suggestion. I have done what you recommended but got Error 404 on the front end and also in the Admin panel. Would you please check my UPDATE in the original post? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have now been able to resolve the issue with installing this extension on Magento 1.9.4:**

- I disabled all Cache including advanced Cache like "Varnish" or "FPC"
- Make sure Compilation is disabled in:

System >> Tools >> Compilation

- Download the ZIP file form GitHub
- Unzip
- Upload via FTP
- Clear all Cache in System >> Cache Management
- System >> Tools >> Compilation, and press the button "Run Compilation Process"
- Log out of the Admin panel and log back in.